# Apply another method to Object/Array

Tags: javascript

How to call another method between method chain?

```js
function double(base) {
  return base * 2;
}
function mapDouble(target) {
  return target.map(double);
}

var foo = [1,2,3].map(double);
console.log(foo); // => [2, 4, 6]
var bar = mapDouble([1,2,3]);
console.log(bar); // => [2, 4, 6]
var qux = [1,2,3].this.call(mapDouble);
console.log(qux);
// => Error {
//  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined",
//  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
//  "lineno": 24,
//  "colno": 23
// }
```

My actual code (I want to write) is

```
[1,2,3].map((value) => {
  return foo;
}).filter((value) => {
  return bar;
}).this.call(mapDouble);
```

Comment: where do you get the values of foo and bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a "monadic" facility to create arbitrary function chains, like for example:

```
function begin() {
    return {
        with: function(x) {
            this.x = x;
            return this;
        },
        do: function (f) {
            this.x = f(this.x);
            return this;
        },
        end: function () {
            return this.x;
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
function whatever(ary) {
    return ary.join('-')
}

result = begin()
    .with([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
    .do(a => a.filter(x => x > 2))
    .do(a => a.map(x => x + 100))
    .do(whatever)
    .end();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in the syntax.

```js
function double(base) {
  return base * 2;
}
function mapDouble(target) {
  return target.map(double);
}

var foo = [1,2,3].map(double);
console.log(foo); // => [2, 4, 6]
var bar = mapDouble([1,2,3]);
console.log(bar); // => [2, 4, 6]
var qux = mapDouble.call(qux, [1,2,3]);
console.log(qux);
```

See this [Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_invoke_call) to understand the behaviour of javascript call function,

It takes arguments which are the arguments to the function you are calling

basic structure is like this

```
functionToCall.call(this, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Hope this helps